# Git rebasing - can another person rebase remote branch for me?

Tags: git

**The Scenario:**

I'm working on a remote git repository with a team of say 20+.  Branches are made, committed to and merged to master frequently.

One colleague and I worked together on a branch for a couple of days.  He rebased the branch, resolved all conflicts and pushed.

When I attempt a pull, I get "automatic merge failed" and a prompt to resolve all conflicts.

When I "git status", I find that I have diverged origin/branch and have over 100 different commits each.

**The problem:**

He had all of my commits to date, had just rebased then pushed, and if I continue with merge, I'm likely redoing the conflict resolution that he already completed.

**The Question**

What is going on here?

What to do?  Why?

**Asides**

I've read a good amount on git, am still learning, and am hoping for a direct answer, pertaining to the git logic, and less to do with the commands associated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm tempted to say "yes, they can make their local copy of the branch, rebase it to anything they want and push it back under the same name" ... But that's when I realize that the answer is No, because by any stretch.of the word, it wouldn't be the same branch anymore!

Answer (score 8):

No, that cannot be done (answer to question in the title of the question).

Rebasing should be done *before* sharing the changesets with others through pushing, pulling, or cloning.

Example of problem, one programmer commits 5 changesets:

```
(1)---(2)---(3)---(4)---(5)
```

Those changesets are shared with another developer, that originally had a clone containing only the first changeset, so he has his own changesets in his repository. Once he has pulled or you pushed, here's what he has:

```
(1)---(2)---(3)---(4)---(5)
  \
   \
    (A)---(B)---(C)
```

Since he wants a linear history, he rebases your changesets on top of his, getting this:

```
(1)---(A)---(B)---(C)---(2')---(3')---(4')---(5')
```

Note that I marked your changesets in his repository with a tick now to indicate that they're "your" changesets, but now affected by his earlier changes, and are thus no longer identical (hashwise or otherwise) with yours.

Then you pull, and here's what you get:

```
(1)---(A)---(B)---(C)---(2')---(3')---(4')---(5')
  \
   \
    (2)---(3)---(4)---(5)
```

Now you have two "copies" of those changesets.

If you haven't done anything after the 5th changeset in your repository, you can probably just strip them out of your repository, but mark that word, "probably", it carries with it strong requirements that you know the state of your repository, and you need to know about each and every clone of the repository.

It doesn't take more than one pull-merge-push before everything is back in a bad state.

**Conclusion**: Do not rebase changesets unless you know what you're doing, and almost certainly don't rebase changesets that are shared.

**Actually**: That warning should be against all forms of history rewriting. Anything that rewrites history **must** be done in isolation, and all clones must be invalidated, otherwise you will have diverging histories and multiple "copies" of the affected changesets. *You do not want to be here!*

Answer (score 2):

What LasseV. Karlsen said is all right. Since he rebased the branch, you can't really pull it and remerge everything.

If you have no more "new" commits, just remove the branch you're trying to pull and pull it. Since all your changeset are present, just reset your branch to be exactly like the one on the server and continue from there. If you have new commits then it will be a bit harder.

First create a copy of your branch:

```
git checkout [branch]
git checkout -b branchCopy
```

Delete the branch (use -f if it doesn't want to delete it because of unmerged)

```
git checkout -d branch
```

Fetch what's on the server (origin could be a different remote) and recreate the branch with what's on the server

```
git fetch [origin]
git checkout origin/branch
git checkout -b branch
```

Now you'll have `branch` and `branchCopy`

Using git log, check which commits you want to add to your branch. and use `cherry-pick` to add them

```
git checkout branch
git cherry-pick "commit"
```

Once all the unmerged commits are added, just push to the server. and delete the "branchCopy"

If you have a lot of diverging changesets between branchCopy and branch. I guess there is a way to rebase a set of commits from `branchCopy` onto `branch` but If you just rebase it. It will add every changes because copied commits have a different hash.

So yes, don't rebase unless you know what you're doing. If you want to rebase and work with many people. The best thing to do is to make sure everyone is aware that you're rebasing.

I guess the first rule for any good time traveler is "Don't change history"

## Tip

Here's a tip to make time traveling safer than ever. At work, I used that flow:

Work on my feature branch and merge in master when its done.

When you're working on your branch, it almost assure you that you won't rebase commits that are present on the master branch. When done, you have to choices. You can merge your branch in master or rebase your branch on master.

If you're rebasing your branch, you'll have to fetch the last master commit and rebase on it and push it as fast as you can. When people will pull it, it should be still fast forward because you didn't change the history of master but the history of your branch.

But to be honest, after using bitbucket, (can't say much about github). I worked with pull requests. It does a merge commit even though the branches are fastforward it might be just easier to just avoid rebasing most of the time. Pullrequest is a wonderful creation that should be used if you use a system that has it.

It might create a merge commit, but it leaves an history of the commits that were merged, by who and you can comment them. People can work on features to be merged and someone may used the pull request to review code when needed and merge the code into master.

Comment: this is exactly what I did after reading Lasse's post.  I saw my previous commits in the log, so I did a hard checkout (using -f which always bugs me to use).  thank you.

Comment: what bugs me is doing `git push -f` when I know that my push isn't fast forward.

Comment: @loic well I must say there is at least one workflow when it's of no fear to use -f: when working *on your very own private branch that no one in the whole wide world has any business basing work on unless they are specifically asking for The Big Trouble*

Comment: @loic ..which is where I personally do this: commit to dev machine, push, pull to test machine, test, fix stupid errors at the dev machine, *amend*, **push -f**, rinse, repeat.